# Is this an 1800's British military uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform, victorian

The photo is of my great-great-grandfather Timothy J. Coffey who lived in Ireland early to mid-1800s

My great-great-grandfather was likely born in Ireland in early 1800's.  His daughter Mary T. Coffey was born in 1846.  We think they were from County Kerry.

Not sure if this is a military uniform or something else. We have no family history of him being in the military, just this photo. Original photo has his name on the back and appears to be a cabinet photo. If this is a military uniform, I would appreciate any information on regiment and rank.

[image: Timothy J. Coffey in uniform]

Comment: My suspicion is it's a Hussars uniform. I'd focus on that sleeve insignia. Have you tried Ancestry.com or similar?

Comment: Have a look at [*A Private of the 7th or Queens Own (Hussars), 1812*](https://collection.nam.ac.uk/detail.php?acc=1950-11-33-11). Note the similarity of the sleeve insignia.

Comment: Hussar's uniforms always  seem to have a system of parallel horizontal rib-like decorative stripes on the chest, however.

Comment: off hand, from the shoulder wings and the trim going down his sleeves I would say he is a musician, probably army, but perhaps not.

Comment: Thank you all. This is a big help. I’ll see if I can learn a bit more about British Hussars. I am also intrigued by possibility of being a musician.  There is musical ability in my family.  I just looked at military drummers of the period and they do seem to have the decorated shoulders and stripes inside the area of their sleeves.  Also, I hadn’t really noticed the full facial hair. All the above will be a big help as I try to figure out more about this relative. 
- Linda